# Getting output of a system command from stdout in C

Tags: c, stdout

I'm writing a C program under Android/Linux that runs a system command. The command outputs some text to stdout, and I'm trying to capture the output into a string or character array.

For example:

```
system("ls");
```

would list the contents of the current directory to stdout, and I would like to be able to capture that data into a variable programmatically in C.

How do I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want to use `popen`. It returns a stream, like `fopen`. However, you need to close the stream with `pclose`. This is because `pclose` takes care of cleaning up the resources associated with launching the child process.

```
FILE *ls = popen("ls", "r");
char buf[256];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), ls) != 0) {
    /*...*/
}
pclose(ls);
```

Comment: This only gets the output stream, ho to get the error stream too?

Comment: @ShashankSingh https://tio.run/##HY3BCgIhGITvPsWPUWhY0EJ7sRYvBUFvUB02V3eFTUXdS9Gzm9tl@AY@ZuSmlzIvjJXj1Ck4xNQZtx0ahIxN8GqNBULhk8@X6wnWHo7gnVeWYO0cVM1qhxngoDDlSA5tgOekb9W@fnCke5UiKZ1BNG/l9MyUgS@ql6OLivwxlCNNsBBiGUvcbVmcTZ6/@Qc