# how to make system() command in C not to display anything on screen?

Tags: php, c, cgi

I have a cgi program in c where I am using a system call for getting the present working directory (pwd).  I used 
`system(pwd);`
, but this will print the directory name on screen(html)  which I don't need as of now.
Is there any way to make the system () function not to display anything,? (Something similar to shell_exec() in php where the output is displayed only when we need it to be displayed)..

Comment: It's unclear what you want. If you want to silence the command, you can redirect the command output to "/dev/null". In your case, why not simply comment out the line altogether?

Comment: Maybe `system("pwd > /dev/null 2>&1");`?

Comment: To get the current work directory from a C rpgoram you might like to use `getcwd()`.

Comment: @devnull: Isn't this a NOP? (besides testing whether `pwd` is available and working)

Comment: @alk This __is__ a no-op.  The assumption was that the OP is executing a command that has a side-effect and produces output that needs to be ignored.

Comment: @devnull You got it! and +1 for the command..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are on a Linux/Unix system.

You can get the pwd from the environment, you don't need to use `system`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

`char *pwd = getenv("PWD");`

For your reference, here is one example on how you can get the output from `system` (there are other ways):

[Getting output of a system command from stdout in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840833/getting-output-of-a-system-command-from-stdout-in-c)